# Exit in a function using Python

Tags: python

A quick function question in Python. Is it possible to stop a function from processing and return early. i.e like this:

```
def _do_something():

    if not exists('/etc/', use_sudo=True):
        # no files don't do any more
        return
    # if ok continue with stuff
    sudo('/etc/init.d/nginx stop')
```

Is this ok? Or is there something like 'exit' ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes it's OK. It would take you less time to just execute this and observe yourself, than posting a question about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a common way of structuring program logic.

Some people would argue that you write your function the other way around, like:

```
def _do_something():
    if exists('/etc/', use_sudo=True):
        sudo('/etc/init.d/nginx stop')
```

because it is shorter and, in a way, more directly represents what you mean by writing the function.

One thing to worry about with the structure that you have in your question is what happens when the function becomes more complicated. It is possible for a large and complicated function with many return statements to actually have *unreachable code*, where the function is guaranteed to return early and there is code at the end of the function that will not be executed.

```
def lol():
    print "first!"
    return
    print "unreachable"
```

In this case, it is trivial to see that "unreachable" will never be printed, but if you have many nested if/else statements, this becomes less obvious. Good IDEs will warn you about unreachable code, but this is something to consider if you choose to program in a simpler text editor.

Side note: Just in case you weren't aware, Python functions that start with one or two underscores often have a "special meaning" attached to them. I'll leave the rest for you to explore.

Answer (score 2):

Your question sounds like " is there a better way to do this?".
no, that looks fine and will work.

For loops you could use the [break-statement](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html), but in a function this is good way to "stop" it - returning `None` implicitly.